# How can I get the voice feedback feature on a headset?

Tags: windows-7, audio, headset

One "feature" that I've found on *some* gaming headsets is the ability to hear yourself speaking in the speakers real-time. This helps you communicate as it's more akin to real-life communication. If the headset lacks this, your own speech is deafened by the fact that you're wearing a headset. Some people love this feedback feature, called "monitor" on some sites, and some people hate it.

I like it. I can't play games without it. Unfortunately, I can't identify any way to ensure this feature is on a specific headset. Searching for "monitor feature on headsets" yields nothing. I've found both cheap headsets that have this, and very expensive ones that don't. I don't want to continue buying headsets at random, hoping they support this apparently obscure ability.

One possibility that a friend and I discovered is that it has to do with headsets that include an external sound processor of some kind (usually USB). Is this the best way to be sure? Is there some name this feature goes by that I'm not familiar with? Must there be hardware support, or can software do this? How can I be sure I'm getting this feature on a headset?

Note: This is **not** the "listen to device" feature you can enable in Windows (this does play your own speech back, but at a delay of around half a second, instead of immediately).

Comment: Please add an OS tag. I've never seend a headset which such a builtin capability. In Linux with pulseaudio, you can loop back the headset mic to the speakers. No external sound processor needed. All solutions on the PC (which *superuser* is for) will have a short delay imposed by the time it takes the CPU to process the audio, but that's way below half a second. Another option would be electronic (amplify mic a bit, couple with headphones via capacitor) which you could add to any headset.

Comment: This feature is also known as "sidetone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a few headsets and looking deeper into the problem, I discovered that there is a software solution (on Windows, at least).

Make sure "listen to this device" is **NOT** checked in your sound settings, then go to the playback devices, right-click on the speakers for your headset, go to Properties, then Levels, and find whichever audio in corresponds to your microphone (sometimes it will say microphone, other times it describes the exact port: mine says "Front Pink In"). This is probably muted. Unmute it and adjust the volume accordingly. Works great!